# Wrap SQL Server column name within list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that wraps columns into single string line.

How to wrap each column name into `sum()` function?

Expected result:
`sum(col) as col, sum(col_n) as col_n`

```
declare @results nvarchar(max)

select @results = coalesce(@results + ', ', '') +  convert(nvarchar(max),name)
from (select 
        name
        from sys.columns  
        where  object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'table') 
        and name like 'col%') t

SELECT @results
```

Comment: Umm, you're already concatenating strings with `+`, so just add `SUM(` and `)` to the strings you're concatenating???  `+ 'SUM(' + convert(nvarchar(max),name) + ')'`

Comment: What is your actual goal here? I *suspect* that you want to execute this statement afterwards? I *doubt* all of your columns are a numerical data type, so `SUM`ing all them doesn't really make a lot of sense. Neither does converting the `name` to an `nvarchar(MAX)`. If you are planning to execute the above (dynamically) you should be using `QUOTENAME` to properly quote your object names.

Comment: Note as well, the above is not a recommended method perform to string aggregation. Use `STRING_AGG` or (on older versions) the `FOR XML PATH` method.

Comment: I'm using SS 2014, thus `STRING_AGG` is not available ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MatBailie spotted the issue ;)

```
select @results_sum = coalesce(@results_sum + ', ', '') + 'SUM(' + convert(nvarchar(max),name) + ') as ' + name
from (select 
        name
        from sys.columns  
        where  object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'table') 
        and name like 'col%') t
```